# Is there a way to get a list of the intrinsic operators of a specific version of Python?

Tags: python

this piece of code from the [doc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements)

```
(x := 0)
```

produces this error.

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-37c757294535>", line 1
    (x := 0)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

then I realized the Env I run is not Python3.8.

Is there a way to get a list of the [intrinsic operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) of a specific  version of Python?

Comment: as I know the only new is `:=` and `@`. But `@` has almost 5 years ([PEP-465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/). So you have almost the same operators in all Python 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PEP 572 is a proposal. It was accepted but the implementation of the assignment expression is not complete yet and so it is not available for the public.

You can do the following to get the list of operators supported by your current Python version:

```py
import operator
dir(operator)
```

Then you can access the [operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) link (pick your Python version) you provided to see what operators the functions actually correspond to. Or you can just look at this for your Python version.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, which is really helpful. Why does the table not include '=' operator?

Comment: Are you thinking of checking for equality or identity? For identity, you can use "is", which is included in the list. For equality, you'd use "==", which is "eq" in the list.